# How to reference string in dynamic query?

Tags: apex, soql, query

In a previous module I did a lookup using the following markup

```
List<Contact> results = Database.query(
        'SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Email ' +
        'FROM Contact ' +
        'ORDER BY ' + sortOrder + ' ASC ' +
        'LIMIT 10'
    );
```

In the current module I am working on, I have to call a list of cases where the `Status = 'New'`. Using this type of markup I can't figure out the proper way to make it work.

```
'SELECT ID, CaseNumber '+
'FROM Case ' +
'WHERE Status = New'
```

I can get it to work when I'm not using the `Database.query()` by using something like below, but otherwise I can't figure out how to get this notation to work correctly.

```
List<Case> results = [Select Id, caseNumber FROM Case Where Status = 'New']
```

Comment: This entire question might be better reframed as how you quote something when you're already in quotes. But I don't know the terminology that would even use that would also be searchable by people unfamiliar with SOQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "escaping" the single quotes. You really should avoid string queries unless they are necessary, but this is a good time to note how [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) works. If you really do need a string query, and you need to accept a string value to filter on, make sure you escape single quotes in the query term. But really, just use static queries unless you have a compelling reason.

> To prevent a SOQL injection attack, avoid using dynamic SOQL queries. Instead, use static queries and binding variables. The vulnerable example above can be re-written using static SOQL as follows:
>
> ```
> public class SOQLController {
>     public String name {
>         get { return name;}
>         set { name = value;}
>     }
>     public PageReference query() {
>         String queryName = '%' + name + '%';
>         queryResult = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE
>            (IsDeleted = false and Name like :queryName)];
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you must use dynamic SOQL, use the `escapeSingleQuotes` method to sanitize user-supplied input. This method adds the escape character () to all single quotation marks in a string that is passed in from a user. The method ensures that all single quotation marks are treated as enclosing strings, instead of database commands.

Comment: Sorry but a bit of this is over the head of us beginners. Is the inline query just everything in the []? And that's what we should be using instead of Database.query?

Comment: I don't use the term "inline", but you could treat it as synonymous with "static". You would perform this inline/static query instead of using `Database.query`, yes.

Comment: Also, you should probably avoid generalizing things you don't understand to others. Stick with first-person-singular pronouns.

Comment: Interesting. When I say "we" I'm usually thinking about me and the people in my organization. Because we don't understand it at the moment.

Comment: Fair enough, but your antecedent above is "us beginners", implying all beginners would struggle with it. I can also be less pedantic, but carefully indicating who you wish to include can make it easier for others to understand where you're coming from. :)

Answer (score 2):

When using this notation adding an apostrophe `'` closes out of the section you are in so you have to use `\'` to quote the value you are using.

So it should read:

```
    'SELECT ID, CaseNumber '+
    'FROM Case ' +
    'WHERE Status = \'New\' '
```